# How to make OpenCv show an image in combination of two color channels?

Tags: python, image, opencv

It's not that difficult to use OpenCV to get an output of one colour channel from an image and that can be easily done.

But is it possible that from the three main BGR colours of an image, I want to see the image in just a combination of Green and Red without Blue using a function directly?

So I am able to perform this above operation by setting all the Blue values to 0 and then see the image, the code of which is below:

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np

    gr = cv2.imread('imagetowork2.jpg')
    gr[:, :, 0] = 0

    cv2.namedWindow("random_image",cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.resizeWindow("random_image",590,332)
    cv2.imshow("random_image",gr)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This above code I had to resort to, because, working with this `gr[:, :, 1:3]` didn't work. And I don't understand why the cv2 functions work with the whole 3 dimensional values but not with two dimensions?

This is the error, one gets, if they try to show the image using `gr[:, :, 1:3]`:

```
error: OpenCV(3.4.5) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\utils.cpp:622: error: (-15:Bad number of channels) Source image must have 1, 3 or 4 channels in function 'cvConvertImage'
```

So my direct and main question is, Is there an inbuilt function to perform this in OpenCV or any other library directly or the set a whole colour value as 0 is the only way to do this?

So this is the image I am working on(can use any kind of image actually):
[image]

And this is the output of what I performed(which I want to get using some in-built function and not setting some values to 0):
[image]

Is this at all possible?

Comment: That's because typically, most images are 1,3, or 4 channels. I'm not aware of any library that handle 2 channel images. Anyway, in python, you can set a channel to `0` quite easily as `img_copy = img.copy(), img_copy[:,:,0] = 0`.

Comment: I know about setting equal to 0 thing and I've mentioned that in the question. But if I am able to perform it by this, can't I do it using a function itself?

The real issue is I am working on many many images where I need to perform this operation in two or more ways in every image. I don't want to create multiple copies of each image. So was hoping I could get output from one object only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess one thing you could do is hold the channels separately and combine what you want for viewing:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import numpy as np
import cv2

im    = cv2.imread('sd71Z.jpg')
b,g,r = cv2.split(im)
zeros = np.zeros_like(b)

cv2.imshow("Zero blue",  cv2.merge([zeros,g,r]))
cv2.imshow("Zero green", cv2.merge([b,zeros,r]))
cv2.imshow('Zero red',   cv2.merge([b,g,zeros]))
cv2.waitKey()
```

[image]

Comment: This was a really interesting and unique approach Mark. Thanks for answering.