# Problem in converting a gray scale image back to an rgb image with user defined transformation function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, rgb

I am working with some RGB image, for some functionality I had to transform the RGB image to Grayscale using some transformation value, then after operations I want to again convert the output image to RGB format with the help of transformation values. How to acheive the same?

**Opencv conversion `cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)` will not produce the original image as it will take values of all 3 channels same, that's why I applied a transformation**

I read the RGB image as:

```
img=cv2.imread("image.png")
```

Then I extract the RGB values as:

```
r, g,b = img[:,:,0], img[:,:,1],img[:,:,2]
```

then I applied transformation to get the gray scale image as:

```
gray = 0.2989 * r + 0.5870 * g + 0.1140 * b
```

How to convert the gray scale image after processing once again back to RGB with the given transformation values?

Comment: what's do you mean `back to RGB`? And also, `opencv` uses `BGR` by default, not `RGB`.

Comment: I had to apply some opencv functions that work with grayscale images, so after the operations, I want to convert the image back to RGB

Comment: Then `cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)` is what you are looking for. Gray color is indeed `BGR` with the same value.

Comment: You want `cv2.split()`, process as grey then `cv2.merge()`

Comment: @QuangHoang I tried the same but it doesn't work, it takes same value for all channels.

Comment: Exactly, what do you think a gray color is represented in BGR?

Comment: @MarkSetchell can you elaborate with some code because I happened to use this but instead got stuck with some error, as  far as I remember. But what the error was I forgot...so maybe I am doing some mistake somewhere!!!!

Comment: @QuangHoang all channels having same value and that's exactly why opencv conversion gray=>rgb/bgr willn't work

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/54183300/2836621

Comment: You said `cv2.cvtColor` won't produce the *original image*, what do you mean by *original image* here?

Comment: @QuangHoang The original image that I have read in img vaiable

Comment: So basically you want to color a grayscale image?

Comment: Yeah to it's original RGB color... I thought that the above transformation values, 0.2989,0.5780, 0.1140 will help in recreating the original RGB image from gray scale but I couldn't construct the same using code

Comment: Thank you @MarkSetchell it worked. I think I would have to work on 3 channels separately (all my processing stuff) and then merge them instead of operating on gray scale

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are trying to operate on the channels independently because you have some algorithm that expects a greyscale image. You can tackle that in a couple of different ways.

So, let's start with this image:

[image]

You can either do it *"in-place"* without separating the image into its component channels like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2

# Load image
img=cv2.imread("start.png",cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

# In-place, zero the Blue, double the Green and halve the Red channels
img[:,:,0]   = 0
img[:,:,1]  *= 2
img[:,:,2] //= 2

# Save
cv2.imwrite('result1.png', img)
```

**Output**

[image]

Or you can split the image into its component channels, work on them separately (and potentially in parallel) and then recombine them at the end back into a BGR image:

```
# Load image and split into component channels
img=cv2.imread("start.png",cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
B, G, R = cv2.split(img)

# Operate on channels independently and out of place
B[...]   = 0
G[...]  *= 2
R[...] //= 2
# Blur the Red too for extra fun
R = cv2.GaussianBlur(R,(25,25),0)

# Recombine channels and save
result = cv2.merge((B,G,R))
cv2.imwrite('result2.png', result)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice explanation on how to separate BGR channels

Answer (score 2):

Its mathematically impossible to transform an grayscale image back to RGB. But, you can convert RGB to [HSV](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html) spaces using `cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)`, perform processing on `value` as grayscale, and transform the results back to RGB.

Comment: There is a link in the answer. you can find some codes there.

Answer (score 1):

When you're adding the red, green and blue channels together into one gray channel you're throwing away information and there is no way (mathematically) you could infer how to split a single gray value into multiple colours again.

Depending on what transformation you're applying to the image in the grayscale format, maybe there will be away to composite your original colour image and the transformed grayscale image into another image that meets your requirements.

Comment: Please elaborate, it's not very clear. A few code segments for the support will surely help

Comment: @Excelsior What you're asking for is theoretically impossible so I can't supply code examples. Depending on what the transformation you're doing to the grayscale image is (but you would have to include all of those details in your question), it might be possible to come up with an algorithm that can merge colour information from the original information back in.